# Insert Method in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

```
public void insert(Buchstabe pBuchstabe,char[] pChar,int pStelle)
{
    if(pBuchstabe==null)
        return;
    int Stelle = pStelle;
    if(baum.isEmpty())
    {
        baum=new BinaryTree(pBuchstabe);
    }
    else {
        if(pStelle < pChar.length)
        {
            if(pChar[Stelle] == '.')
            {
                Mybaum lTree=this.getLeftTree();
                Stelle++;
                lTree.insert(pBuchstabe,pChar,Stelle);
                this.baum.setLeftTree(lTree.baum);
            }
            else
            if(pChar[Stelle]=='-')
            {
                Mybaum rTree=this.getRightTree();
                Stelle++;
                rTree.insert(pBuchstabe,pChar,Stelle);
                this.baum.setLeftTree(rTree.baum);
            }
        }
        else
            return;
    }
}
```

So this is my insert Method. The Problem is that it only adds the last Buchstabe which i pass to it to the BinaryTree. So it will get a Buchstabe, a char Array with some '.' or '-' code in it and a integer which starts at 0 when the insert merhod is called at the beginning. There is no real error but i get this output : http://puu.sh/h9I4E/beee4f30a9.png  .
It should create a Binary Tree with 26 Items but only one is showing up on the wrong side.

Comment: how you are calling insert method first time??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert Method in a BinarySearchTree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543903/insert-method-in-a-binarysearchtree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Problem it is the second Part of the insert it takes the left instead of the right tree.

```
 if(pChar[Stelle]=='-')
        {
            Mybaum rTree=this.getRightTree();
            Stelle++;
            rTree.insert(pBuchstabe,pChar,Stelle);
            this.baum.**setLeftTree**(rTree.baum);
        }
```